# If two questions are identical but have entirely different answers, are they duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407852/why-does-vb-allow-me-in-field-initialization-but-c-sharp-explicitly-deny-this?noredirect=1#comment43263990_27407852) and got in a discussion about whether my question was a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381091/why-in-c-sharp-this-is-not-allowed-in-member-initializer-but-in-vb-net-me-is-al).  When I reviewed the latter question, I was not happy with the answers because, in my opinion, they didn't actually answer the question.

Meanwhile, my question was answered to my satisfaction.

I look at "questions" as a concept, i.e. the "question" is actually comprised of 1.) the query, 2.) all the answers, and 3.) all the comments, taken as a whole.  So, given that, to me it seems like two "questions" are not actually duplicates if one of them has different answers than the other, especially if the one that is the "earlier" question doesn't have any good answers.

Comment: If a duplicate question could only be a duplicate if ALL answers and ALL comments are duplicates as well there wouldn't be a single valid duplicate on that site.

Comment: If you aren't happy with the existing answers, you try to get attention to the question by editing it or placing a bounty on it to try to get new/better answers.

Comment: Why so many down votes?

Comment: @roryap On Meta downvotes can mean disagreement with an assertion you made in your question. See the first comment on your question for a reason people may be disagreeing with you.

Comment: Well, probably as a fast way to say we disagree strongly with your premise (as it would destroy any Q&A site adopting it). Still, it's meta, so they don't really count for much anyway. (I just hope noone went to the main-site and voted according to their opinion on this post there.)

Comment: @Louis -- Ahh, I see.  I've never posted here before.

Comment: In the event that duplicate questions both have high-quality answers, moderators do have the ability to merge the answers from one into the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, two identical questions can have widely different answers. They're still identical questions.

It's just the same as any single question can have widely different answers.

What's more problematic is if two (or more) apparently different questions have the *same* answer. Then that's an **indication** that the questions are duplicate, but it's not sufficient to mark them as such. However, if they're not identical then the answers should be tailored to the specifics of each question.

Comment: I really like your answer. It is a pity the question got so poor score as it means this answer could be deleted by @ryoryap if he decides so to increase his SO score.